# Finding max value for a column in dataframe for each day in R

Tags: r

Need to find the max value of a column count in the data frame and group it by day. This is the sample data it is having:

```
Date               count
7/28/2014 00:30:31  95
7/28/2014 01:30:57  62
7/28/2014 15:42:42  112
7/28/2014 15:42:42  150
7/31/2014 17:12:22  12
7/31/2014 04:45:47  97
8/2/2014  21:12:06  85
8/2/2014 23:05:09   96
8/2/2014 18:17:42   48
8/2/2014 19:53:02   89
8/2/2014 14:18:38   201
```

My requirement is to find max value of count. How can this be done in R?

sorry i just forgot to mention. the date column is of data type timestamp or is having timestamp format value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that your data is in a `data.frame` called `bar`, you can use `by()`:

```
> with(bar,by(count,Date,max))
Date: 7/28/2014
[1] 150
-------------------------
Date: 7/31/2014
[1] 97
-------------------------
Date: 8/2/2014
[1] 201
```

Comment: this works for date data type but not for timestamp. can you provide with an answer for timestamp

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, another option with base R is to use `aggregate` (assuming your data is called `dat`):

```
aggregate(count ~ Date, data = dat, max)
#       Date count
#1 7/28/2014   150 
#2 7/31/2014    97
#3  8/2/2014   201
```

Using the package `dplyr` in case you have a large data set and need better speed:

```
library(dplyr)

dat %>% group_by(Date) %>% summarize(maxCount = max(count))
#Source: local data frame [3 x 2]
#
#       Date maxCount
#1 7/28/2014      150
#2 7/31/2014       97
#3  8/2/2014      201
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` for bigger datasets

```
 library(data.table)
 setDT(dat)[, list(maxCount=max(count)), by=Date]
 #        Date maxCount
 #1: 7/28/2014   150
 #2: 7/31/2014    97
 #3:  8/2/2014   201
```

Benchmarks for slightly bigger datasets

```
set.seed(455)
dat1 <- data.frame(group=sample(1:5000, 1e7, replace=TRUE), count=sample(200, 1e7, replace=TRUE))

f1<- function() dat1 %>% group_by(group) %>% summarize(maxCount = max(count))

f2 <- function() setDT(dat1)[, list(maxCount=max(count)), by=group]
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(f1(),f2(), unit="relative")
# expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# f1() 1.914458 2.049166 2.221317 2.256047 2.888778   100
# f2() 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000   100
```

Answer (score 0):

tapply has easy syntax and gives a clear tabular output:

```
with(ddf, tapply(count, Date, max))
7/28/2014 7/31/2014  8/2/2014 
      150        97       201
```